# JQuery and the validate plugin

Tags: jquery, validation

Rather than write my own validation I thought i would use JQuery instead however i'm not finding this easy either. I have a few questions which I hope someone can answer. Firstly, the error messages are only appearing when I click submit. How can I get them to appear after exiting each field? Here's my code for validation.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#orderForm").validate({
        rules: {
            shipFirstName: {
                required: true,
            },
            shipFamilyName: {
                required: true,
            },
            shipPhoneNumber: {
                required: true,
            },
            shipStreetName: {
                required: true,
            },
            shipCity: {
                required: true,
            },
            billEmailAddress: {
                required: true,
            },
            billPhoneNumber: {
                required: true,
            },
            billCardNumber: {
                required: true,
            },
            billCardType: {
                required: true,
            },
        }, //end of rules
    }); // end of validate
    }); //end of function
```

This is my HTML code for the form. I won't show the styling but I have changed it to display a red font.

Code:

```
<form id="orderForm" method="post" action="x">
      <table id="formTable" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h3>Shipping and Billing Information</h3>
          </td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="shipFirstname">First Name</label></td>
          <td><input id="shipFirstName" type="text" name="shipFirstName" maxlength=
          "30" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="shipFamilyName">Surname</label></td>
          <td><input id="shipFamilyName" type="text" name="shipFamilyName" maxlength="30" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="shipPhoneNumber">Contact Telephone Number</label></td>
          <td><input id="shipPhoneNumber" type="text" name="shipPhoneNumber" maxlength="30" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="shipStreetName">Street Name</label></td>
          <td><input id="shipStreetName" type="text" name="shipStreetName" maxlength="30" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="shipCity">City</label></td>
          <td><input id="shipCity" type="text" name="shipCity" maxlength="30" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="shipPostalCode">Postal Code</label></td>
          <td><input id="shipPostalCode" type="text" name="shipPostalCode" maxlength="30" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="billEmailAddress">Email address</label></td>
          <td><input id="billEmailAddress" type="text" name="billEmailAddress" maxlength="30" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="billPhoneNumber">Contact Telephone Number</label></td>
          <td><input id="billPhoneNumber" type="text" name="billPhoneNumber" maxlength="30" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="fidelityCardNumber">Fidelity card</label></td>
          <td><input id="fidelityCardNumber" type="text" name="fidelityCardNumber" maxlength="30" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="billCardNumber">Credit Card Number</label></td>
          <td><input id="billCardNumber" type="text" name="billCardNumber" maxlength="30" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="billCardType">Credit Card Type</label></td>
          <td><select id="billCardType" name="billCardType">
            <option value="...">
              Choose your card...
            </option>
            <option value="visa">
              Visa
            </option>
            <option value="mastercard">
              Mastercard
            </option>
          </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="instructions">Instructions</label></td>
          <td>
          <textarea id="instructions" name="instructions" rows="8" cols="30">
Enter your requirements here or comments.
</textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><input id="submit" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
```

I also want to use regexs for the postcode and fidelity card. How do I incorporate these into the script? Is this right? Where do I put it?

```
$.validator.addMethod('shipPostalCode', function (value) {
    return /^[A-Z]{2}\d{1,2}\s\d{1,2}[A-Z]{2}$/.test(value);
    }, 'Please enter a valid Postal Code');
    $.validator.addMethod('fidelityCardNumber', function (value) {
    return /^[A-Z]{1}([A-Z]|\d){4}\s?([A-Z]|\d){5}\s?([A-Z]|\d){3}\d{1}(\!|\&|\@|\?){1}$/.test(value);
    }, 'Please enter a valid card number');
```

One final thing. Can this script be put in an external js file easily? I am trying to get as much out of the html file as possible.

Thanks

Comment: yes you can add it to external js file quiet easily. Has for making it work, I have not tried the form validation yet with jquery. Just looking through the docs, appears you can use the onfocusout for form fields and onclick for check boxes and radio buttons. sorry I can be of more help

Comment: I have managed to sort out the problem about the error messages not displaying when you click out of the field. I used this code:

$("...").validate({ 
  onfocusout: function(element) { 
    this.element(element); 
  } 



}); 

I'm still really stuck on the custom method though with the regexs

Answer (score 2):

$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#orderForm").validate({
            onfocusout: true,
            rules: {
                    shipFirstName: {
                            required: true,
                    },
                    shipFamilyName: {
                            required: true,
                    },
                    shipPhoneNumber: {
                            required: true,
                    },
                    shipStreetName: {
                            required: true,
                    },
                    shipCity: {
                            required: true,
                    },
                    billEmailAddress: {
                            required: true,
                    },
                    billPhoneNumber: {
                            required: true,
                    },
                    billCardNumber: {
                            required: true,
                    },
                    billCardType: {
                            required: true,
                    },
            }, //end of rules
        }); // end of validate
        }); //end of function

That'll make it so that every time you leave a field, it validates it automatically. :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work, but you first have to fill something in the form. Try writing something in the First name, then delete it and change focus.

Comment: Are you saying my script should work or the solution from aduljr? I have done what you said and it still doesn't work unless you click submit

Answer (score 1):

As far as adding your own validation method, check out http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage

You might also want to explore using this method instead:

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules({
  name: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 2
  },
  zip: {
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 5
  }
});
```

from the example at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addClassRules#rules

Lastely, http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation indicates that you could also validate like this

which would be cleaner and less JS for you to write.

Answer (score 1):

By using 'addMethod' call, you are actually adding a 'type' of validation which could be used in your main 'validate' method call.

```
$.validator.addMethod('postalCode', 
    function (value, element) 
    {
          return this.optional(element) || /^[A-Z]{2}\d{1,2}\s\d{1,2}[A-Z]{2}$/.test(value);
    }, 'Please enter a valid Postal Code');


$.validator.addMethod('creditCardNumber', 
    function(value, element) 
    {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[A-Z]{1}([A-Z]|\d){4}\s?([A-Z]|\d){5}\s?([A-Z]|\d){3}\d{1}(\!|\&|\@|\?){1}$/.test(value);
    }, 'Please enter a valid card number');
```

Put this code in the same JS file where you have other validation code.

Then, modify your validate method call to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#orderForm").validate({

        rules: {

                    //Your other rules

                    shipPostalCode: { postalCode: true },
                    fidelityCardNumber : { creditCardNumber : true }

                }

    })
   }
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myform').validate({ onfocusout: function(element) { $(element).valid(); } };
```

This will also work.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("stateUS", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) ||
    /^(?:A[KLRZ]|C[AOT]|D[CE]|FL|GA|HI|I[ADLN]|K[SY]|LA|M[ADEINOST]|N[CDEHJMVY]|O[HKR]|PA|RI|S[CD]|T[NX]|UT|V[AT]|W[AIVY])*$/.test(value);
}, "The specified US State is invalid");`
```

For validating two letter abbreviations for US states and DC.

Wanted to comment on the above, but not enough rep - Salty's answer says to use

```
onfocusout: true
```

However, according to the docs (and trying it) that's not a valid setting.
http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate

> A boolean true is not a valid value.

If you're setting truthiness to that value, you need to set a callback function which gets two arguments, element and event - just like Alistair's answer.